# MATLAB Compiler Runtime - how to run it?

Tags: matlab, runtime

I'm supposed to install the MATLAB compiler runtime for class purposes in one of my subjects at University. I have installed it and followed the guide - and this is my silly question: How do I run it? I mean, shouldn't there be some sort of icon or file I need to click to run the actual program?

It shows up on my list of installed programs (under `controlpanel -> programs and features`), and I have checked the folders where i installed it, but there doesn't seem to be any file or anything I can use to actually run it.

Maybe I misunderstood the purpose of MCR, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Also, note that I am still new to anything computer-related that is more advanced than basic HTML and opening zipped files.

Comment: You need to write Matlab code and generate a .dll (or executable maybe). Then this .dll can be run on a PC that has either Matlab or MCR installed. But you don't click and start MCR.

Comment: Oh, I totally misunderstood the teachers instructions then! Now it makes a lot more sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This question was already correctly answered in the comments by @seb, but to make sure it does not remain open I will post the answer here:

> You need to write Matlab code and generate a .dll (or executable
>   maybe). Then this .dll can be run on a PC that has either Matlab or
>   MCR installed. But you don't click and start MCR.

And in addition to that I have added a description of how I see the MCR:

Think of the MCR as a bundle of complicated functions. When you compile a program you will just have the references to those functions in your program. Most of the content will actually be drawn from the MCR when your program is run.

---

That being said, if you actually want students to work with matlab (not just with programs pre built by the teacher) you will actually need to install Matlab, and not the MCR.